# If the $n$-th term of a geometric progression $5,-\frac 52, \frac 54$.. is $\frac{5}{1024}$, then n is

Tags: geometric-series

Common ratio = $r=\frac{-1}{2}$

First term=$a$

$$\frac{5}{1024}=5\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{1024}=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$
$$1024=(-2)^{1-n}$$
$$(-2)^{10}=(-2)^{1-n}$$
Then $$10=1-n$$
$$n=-9$$ which makes so sense. How should I get the right answer?

Comment: The power should remain the same if you took the reciprocal of the base. i.e. it should be $$1024=(-2)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Note:  $4^5=1024$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started to be wrong from the third line. You take a $-1$ power both side but you do too much on your right side, it should be:
$\left[\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}\right]^{-1}=\left(-2\right)^{n-1}\text{ or }\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1-n}$

Comment: I hope you don't mind me changing that. I thought using the $/$ was unclear and could be interpreted as division.

Comment: ok that's fine for me. It is better actually :D

Comment: Why wouldn’t it change? Isn’t $\frac 1a = a^{-1}$?

Comment: For $\left(a^b\right)^{-1}$, it can be expressed as $a^{-b}$ or $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^b$, but not $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{-b}$

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$a_n = a_1 r^{(n-1)}$$

Plug in $r=-1/2$, $a_1=5$ and $a_n =5/1024$  to get

$$n=11$$

Comment: The OP clearly applies this formula but makes a mistake.

Comment: Actually, he knows the sequence, but he has something doing wrong in while doing this question, so please answer correctly

Comment: Sure, I mean I could make out that it was 11, but I needed a proper way to solve it.

Comment: @Aditya Sorry for misunderstanding